# Gerar um APK por linha de comando?

Tags: android, android-studio

Como faço para gerar um APK, projeto android studio via linha de comando?
Gostaria de saber se tem como chamar um arquivo .bat e ele exportar o apk em uma pasta.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Android usa o sistema de construção Ant. Para que você possa criar um **build.xml** e arquivo **build.properties** para o seu projeto.

Você vai precisar para criar o **build.xml** arquivo primeiro no entanto:

> android update project -p.

Isso irá gerar um arquivo **build.xml**.

Provavelmente, você deve personalizar as etapas de construção e metas para o seu projeto. Uma boa idéia, no seu caso seria a de ter o build.properties arquivo gerado pelo sua IDE para a compilação específica. Então incluí-lo através do arquivo build.xml.

Em particular, será necessário especificar no arquivo **build.properties**, onde as chaves de assinatura são, e que a senha é:

**Build.Properties:**

> key.store=keystore.dat
>
> key.alias=signing_key
>
> key.store.password=password123
>
> key.alias.password=password123

O processo de construção utilizando ant também permite que você faça as substituições de variáveis ​​em arquivos Java, que pode ser uma outra idéia. Seria permitem que você personalize o processo de construção ainda em um cliente por base cliente.

Por padrão, a compilação é acionado por:

> ant clean ant release